# URL accessible by curl but not browser (connection reset)

Tags: node.js, ssl, curl

I have a backend API on port 3000 using an SSL certificate. I have it hooked up to my frontend and whenever it tried to query the API I get 'connection reset'. When I try to curl `https://example.com:3000/ping`, it returns the expected `pong`. But when I try to curl the same URL not from within my EC2 ssh, curl returns `LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL`. Where is the problem? Is it in the SSL cert or in something I'm not catching?

Comment: I doubt that this is a certificate problem. I would rather say that some firewall is blocking the access from outside.

Comment: I've tried over and over again to open the port with iptables. I've allowed traffic in and out to port 3000. I also allowed port 3000 in my ec2 security groups.

Comment: I recommend you do a packet capture on the EC2 system to see if the connections from outside on port 3000 actually get received by the local system and how it reacts to these. I have no idea of your exact setup but other options might be that it is only listening on localhost or only on addresses not accessible from outside or that there are IP-based restrictions inside the application itself.

Comment: sounds like a libressl bug to me. are you running an ancient version of libressl?

Comment: got the same problem with rabbitmq on rancher desktop